# How to disable auto gradient effect in QHeaderView?

Tags: qt, gradient, qheaderview

I have type some code to fill the whole QTreeWidget with single color:

```
myTree->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid green; background: green;");
```

But as a result, the header color is not a solid color. Instead, the header has a gradient with two contrast lines.

How can I disable this effect and fill the header with a solid color?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QHeaderView::section {border: 0px solid green; background: green;}
```

It's working.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/101700/how-to-disable-auto-gradient-effect-in-qheaderview/2

Answer (score 0):

You can change the shape and the shadow of your header with:

```
myTree->header()->setFrameShape(QFrame::NoFrame);
myTree->header()->setFrameShadow(QFrame::Plain);
```

It should remove the gradient.